# How do I copy GMail's drag and drop labeling function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In a web application I am making I want to create the same effect that GMail has for dragging and dropping labels and conversations.

Basically I want to be able to make an ondrag function that attaches a "new" html element to the cursor, and upon releasing it over certain elements I want to execute my given functionality that is aware of both the dragged element and the element over which the drop occured.

I don't want to move any elements around. I want to make a function that let's the original elements stay in place and only react to the dragging of some new element.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this : http://www.finrik.at/temp/drag_drop/index.html
[here](http://translate.google.at/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.finrik.at/content/drag-amp-drop-mit-jquery) is the how to. and you'll need jQuery plgin (www.jquery.com)